# Dynamic Condition Objects

Tags: business-objects

In BO XI 3.1, is it possible to create a condition object that filters on multiple tables, without adding all of those tables to the query if they weren't already present?

For example, if I have several tables which all contain both current and historical data, and each table has a flag to indicate if the record is current or historical - can I create a **single** "Current Data" condition that filters **all** of such tables to pull only current data? The catch would be that the query might not be selecting from all of these tables, and I don't want the inclusion of the condition to add joins to tables I'm not selecting from.

In other words, can a condition check which tables are being used by the query and apply filters only on those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a self-restricting join to each of those tables, and use an `@prompt` function to ask whether to return current data or historical data. If you use the same text and same datatype for all of the prompts in each self-restricting join, the prompt will only be shown once, and will only be applied to the tables that are actually used in the generated query.

The self-restricting join could look something like:

```
<table>.<history_flag> 
= ￼@Prompt('Select current or historical data','A',{'C','H'}, Mono, constrained, , {'C'})
```

In the above example, we assume that the flag is an alphanumeric column (`A`) with values C or H (`{'C','H'}`). The user is only allowed to pick from these two values (`constrained`) and only one value can be chosen (`Mono`). The default choice is set to current data (`{'C'}`).

Have a look at the Universe Designer guide for the @prompt syntax. Self-restricting joins are explained in the same manual.